# How to use the following Regexp to run as a replace/update sql query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to Mysql and Regexp and wanted help in running the below regexp to clear whitespaces from a column called description in my table.

```
string = string.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Can someone please help? I can do basic query's.

Comment: Do you **absolutely** want to use regex ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: No i am open to suggestions i want to remove all white spaces apart from one whitespace thats why i though Regexp was best.

Answer (score 2):

No need for **RegEx** in that case. 
You can simply use the `Trim()` function from mySQL.

It will simply remove all the white spaces :

```
SELECT TRIM('      removeSpaces      ');
--------

OUTPUT : [removeSpaces]
```

Comment: Sorry I want to keep one space not remove all.